# What is the meaning of static size_t length(const char_type* __s) {return strlen(__s);}? How do i solve it?

Tags: c++, xcode, reversi

I'm doing an assignment using c++. I'm writing a reversi game using Xcode. I get the thread above when I place a marker in the top left box i.e. (1,1). I just want to know what does it mean and how can I solve it. Thank you. P.S the thread pointed at the displayTop() function.

```
void displayTop(){

cout << "    ";

for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
    cout << "+----";
}

cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: You do really think anyone wants to read 700 lines of code for you? Please make an effort and shorten the listing to show us the problem. I also don't know what in fact the problem is. But according to title. It's just a function that returns length of given string.

Comment: @DawidPi I'm sorry for the mistake but i'm new to SO. Plus my intention was to show the complete code so that whoever is reading it can see the whole problem, but anyways, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I don't see threads being created, and even if they were, I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: @JamesRoot, in think he means "string" - translation ambiguity.

Comment: @JamesRoot That's my issue. My question is this thread is created when I run the entire game. When I want to display a black circle in the top left corner slot, this thread comes up. This function is to display the top of the reversi board.

Comment: What is the error? how does it relate to your code?

Comment: @CarlNorum I'm sorry I don't know, but what popped up in Xcode was thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=exc_i386_gpflt), which pointed to the line in the title and the displayTop() fucntion.

Comment: @Mahmoud Dawlatly Where is ROWS declared? Ugh so bad at comments right now. EDIT: Forget about ROWS. I'm pretty sure you have heap corruption.

Comment: @JamesRoot What i expect is this: when i enter "1 1", a black circle is placed in the box with the co-ordinates (1,1) which is the top left corner one. What happens is the execution stops and the thread is created. This thread points to the line (cout << "    ";) which is the first line

Comment: @JamesRoot ROWS is a global constant.

Comment: @Mahmoud Dawlatly I'm confident that what is happening is you've accidentally overwritten some important piece of memory. Step through your program with a debugger and pay important attention to where your pointers are going. Or use a memory tool if you have one. I think that somewhere a pointer is getting assigned an incorrect value and when it is written to, it is obliterating something important that `cout` needed.

Comment: @JamesRoot I'm sorry I don't understand what you are saying, as I'm still learning c++ in the university. If you can direct me to the steps on xcode, I would appreciate that.

Comment: @Mahmoud Dawlatly Are you working with pointers in this project?

Comment: @JamesRoot No I'm not.

Comment: @Mahmoud Dawlatly Anywhere that you call a function that you yourself didn't write, make sure you passed the right parameters. It's then possible that an invalid parameter is making a library function overwrite something relating to the string literal being sent to `cout`.

Comment: @JamesRoot I've looked at every function in the code, the ones I wrote and didn't write and checked all the parameters, but they are all correct. I have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: @Mahmoud Dawlatly Everytime you run it, the same error in the same place results, correct? And you went through it with a debugger to make sure the correct values were being passed in every function call?

Comment: @JamesRoot Yes every time. I'm 100% sure that the function calls are using correct values

Comment: @Mahmoud Dawlatly When you go to enter (1,1), what exactly do you type? Just `11`?

Comment: @JamesRoot Yes 1 space 1 and then enter

Comment: @Mahmoud Dawlatly There are so many incorrect array indices I can't possibly list them all. An array is a pointer in disguise, and by giving it wrong indices you can cause the problem that you have right now.

Comment: For starters, you declare `board` with `[COLS][ROWS]` and use `[ROWS][COLS]` everywhere else. Then you either access the array with negative values or values that exceed the array bounds, like Bo Persson notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one place where you index outside the board. After that, anything can happen.

```
void clearBoard(){
    for (int i = 0; i <= ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= COLS; j++) {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
```

It should be `<`, or preferrably `!=`, to stay inside the bounds of the board.